# Symfony - Optimize form with repetitive EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

The current website I'm developing right now is running Symfony 3.4.

One of my entities is `Contact`:
I get a very large MySQL table with **~ 14.000 rows** of contact profile :

| Name | Email | Phone number | Allocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brand Peter | peter.brand@aol.com | 49594885403 | Bla blabla |
| .... | ... | ... | ... |

Then I have another Entity `Event`, with its custom form `EventForm` including 6 different slots referring to the `Contact` entity:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

/*****
** Here all my others 'use'
*****/

use AppBundle\Entity\Contact;
use AppBundle\Repository\ContactRepository;

class EventForm
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            
        // A lot of ->add(), not revelant for my issue
        
        ->add('client1', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Client::class,
            'query_builder' => function(ClientRepository $repo) {
                return $repo->getAll();
            }
        ])
        
        ->add('client2', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Client::class,
            'query_builder' => function(ClientRepository $repo) {
                return $repo->getAll();
            }
        ])
        
        // ->add('client3'), same as above
        // ->add('client4'), same as above
        // ->add('client5'), same as above
        // ->add('client6'), same as above

        ;

    }
```

That works perfect! **BUT** each query is processing like 2 second then the total loading time of the form is more than 10 seconds. Is there a way to optimize my form in order to only perform the `$repo->getAll()` query once? I also tried `findAll()` but the performance is the same.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Adding clients? Or changing them? You for sure should remove the query building part. You are retrieving all your clients 6 times! Just write a query builder above your $builder and use the returned data as variable for each client. Also why do you have 6 in specific? Could it ever be more or less? I think you should generate these 6 `->add` things somehow.

Comment: I also think it is important to show your controller (what happens after the submit). And all your ->add() codes. Since your loading time is all based on these things. 10 seconds loading time is really way too big. Test what part takes the most time and do specific optimalisations there. What you are asking now is too big and unclear imo. Its not specific enough to fix your loading time the way you want. How can 6 query's take 2 seconds if you have 10 seconds load time? 6 * 2 = 12. Not 10...

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that would be to to create a property $clientChoices where you store once and for all your repo->getAll() result. For that, you have to define  your form as a service : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_dependencies.html.

You would then inject the EntityManager to get what you want in the constructor, something like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

/*****
** Here all my others 'use'
*****/

use AppBundle\Entity\Contact;
use AppBundle\Repository\ContactRepository;

class EventForm
{
    private $clientChoices = [];

    public function __constructor(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->clientChoices = $entityManager->getRepository(Client::class)->getAll();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            
        // A lot of ->add(), not revelant for my issue
        
        ->add('client1', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Client::class,
            'choices' => $this->clientChoices,
        ])
        
        ->add('client2', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Client::class,
            'choices' => $this->clientChoices,

            }
        ])
        
        // ->add('client3'), same as above
        // ->add('client4'), same as above
        // ->add('client5'), same as above
        // ->add('client6'), same as above

        ;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your code works perfectly but there is a very strange behavior: still no change in performance (~ 12sec. of loading time). However, if I only edit `'choices' => $this->clientChoices` to  `'choices' => []` and keep the repository call in the constructor... then loading time is 4sec. So weird!